# how can i send information from a java applet to my html/javascript/css?

Tags: java, applet, colors

I have a simple page with a header on top and a java applet on the bottom. the applet uses an input (passed via php get parameter, aka index.php?url=http://www.image.com/img.jpg. This java script will calculate the average color throughout the picture. i'd like the header to match this average color.

how can i send this information back to the DOM?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is how to access Java variable from Java script](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0171.html)
[Here is how to call Java method from JavaScript](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0170.html)
[Here is how to call JavaScript from Applet](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0172.html)

Comment: ahh wonderful! apologies, as i did search around. i suppose it was wrong keywords.